# LightSaml + ADFS not receiving SAMLResponse

Tags: php, symfony, saml, adfs3.0

I have tried everything that I could and can't find a way to make it work.
I already have simplesamlphp working with my ADFS. Now I am implementing the lightsaml in a symfony project with the AFDS. I have compared both and they look exactly the same except that in the assertion consumer service of the simplesamlphp I am receiving a POST data from the federation server, while the lightsaml assertion consumer is blank.

1) Federation Service Relying Party (End Points)

2) simplesamlphp - destination after authentication (receiving claims)

3) lightsaml - destination after authentication (not receiving claims)

[screen image from the 3 points above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb15H.png)

I am sending the same claims for both relying parties.
Any ideas what I am missing?